# Why is InitializeCulture not being called

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I have a base page class that implements protected override void InitializeCulture() however it is never called during the page rendering process?

I have added the following code to my base page

```
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            var cultureCode = ConfigManager.GetConfig("System:CultureCode") ?? "en-GB";
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureCode);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
```

The value returned by `ConfigManager.GetConfig("System:CultureCode")` is en-US.

The overridden method is never called and the `txtCulture.Text = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` in my test page always returns en-GB!

Comment: Not sure, we do this in Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax, which might be a better place for it?

Comment: Thanks Matthew I've added this code everywhere, I have just tried your suggestion also, however by the time my test page loads the culture is back to en-GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inherit `BasePage` from `System.Web.UI.Page`, I reproduced it worked

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            var cultureCode = ConfigManager.GetConfig("System:CultureCode") ?? "en-GB";
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureCode);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
    }
```

Default page

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage
{
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {                   
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: My ```Test.aspx``` page inherits from a ```ProtectedPage``` class and that inherits from A ```Page``` class and that in turn inherits from ```System.Web.UI.Page```

Comment: Can you check with your source code, if you reproduce by my source code you will see it alway call InitializeCulture()

Comment: Yes it works in a blank project so something must be causing the issue elsewhere in the code, how and why is a mystery I'll investigate further.

Comment: Thank you, your comment made me delve deeper and I found another InitializeCulture method hidden within a #region block within the ProtectedPage class!!